# How to Integrate Visual c++ to eclipse for opengl programming

Tags: eclipse, opengl, glut

I am trying to Integrate visual c++ to eclipse for opengl programming . . here are the steps I did..

> 1. created a new project in eclipse.
> 2. added these lib path and libraries in settings of the project properties
>
>    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib
>    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib
>    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\Kernel32.Lib
>        copied the glut libs to its respective places..

so far  a simple c++ program worked .. but when I try to execute a simple opengl program

```
#include <glut.h>

void Draw(void);
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250,250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200,200);
    glutCreateWindow("Tutorial");
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutMainLoop();

}

void Draw(void) {

}
```

what possibly could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution .. everything was right but my system Is 64 bit windows 8. and I copied the glut.dll to system32 folder, but it should be placed in sysWOW64 . Now it works..

Comment: Actually you should place the GLUT DLL alongside your program's binary, not in the system wide installation directories. Those are reserved for system libraries.